# WPF property grid, event handler adding with 'ref' parameter.

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling, propertygrid

I've been encountering a very strange behavior of Visual Studio 2010's WPF property grid. I'm developing a component toolset with large set of properties and event handlers. **ref** parameter is causing problems.

In one of my objects, I have `PositionChanged` event handler with **ref** parameter defined like this:

```
public delegate void PositionChangedHandler(LineSeriesCursor sender, double newValue, **ref** bool cancelRendering); 

public event PositionChangedHandler PositionChanged = null;
```

When I make an instance of `LineSeriesCursor` and define event handler

```
LineSeriesCursor cursor = new LineSeriesCursor(); 
cursor.PositionChanged += [TAB][TAB]
```

it creates the handler method stub correctly:

```
cursor.PositionChanged += new LineSeriesCursor.PositionChangedHandler(cursor_PositionChanged);
void cursor_PositionChanged(LineSeriesCursor sender, double newValue, **ref** bool cancelRendering)
{
           //this works and compiles then OK. 
}
```

But, if I add the `LineSeriesCursor` in WPF property grid, and then navigate to `LineSeriesCursor` tag in XAML, add `PositionChanged` event handler from property grid, the method stub is created without **ref**, as follows:

```
private void LineSeriesCursor_PositionChanged(LineSeriesCursor sender, double newValue, bool cancelRendering)
{
    //Does not compile, because of invalid method parameter list. **ref** is missing.
}
```

It sounds like bug of Visual Studio 2010 to me. Any similar experiences or advice on this matter?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not follow the microsoft way and derive from [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.eventargs.aspx)

For example

```
public class PositionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public bool Cancel {get;set;}
   public int NewValue {get;set;}

} 

public event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs> PositionChanged {get;set;}


protected virtual void OnPositionChanged(int newValue)
{
    if (this.PositionChanged !=null)
    {
        var args = new PositionChangedEventArgs(){NewValue = newValue};
        this.PositionChanged(this,args);
        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            //Do something to cancel..
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
cursor.PositionChanged += (sender,e) =>
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    var x = e.NewValue;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I really appreciate the level you are commited in sharing your experience. I'm already familiar with the EventArgs pattern. The problem is that hundreds of developers are already using our libraries and changing the API is something that we certainly want to avoid. I was just wondering if this is really a Visual Studio bug that prevents the 'ref' from appearing from XAML and property grid. Very annoying feature.